# flask-user, wont set active false as deafult

Tags: flask-login

I am using flask-user as login system. 
I want each new user to be set as active false as default so an admin can activate the account after review.

But the record is always inserted as true. Where is it set? My model default it to false. Where can I change it to always insert new users with active false?

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email_confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean(), nullable=False, server_default='0')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:
`active = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=False)`

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. I have tried different varieties.

    active = db.Column(db.Boolean(), nullable=False, server_default='0')
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean(), nullable=False, default=False)
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean(), nullable=False, default=False, server_default='0')

All of them return active true..

Comment: are you using `sqlalchemy`?

Comment: Maybe remove the `nullable` flag

Comment: Tried that too, without luck :( active must be set somewhere from flask-user?

Comment: can you post your is_active method for User class

Comment: Hmm, How do you mean? Sorry, faily new to this. Do you mean like dir(User.is_authenticated) that is just printing another dict of methods.
I have not written is_active myself, it is from flask-user (I expect inhereted from flask-login which it depends on)

Comment: you need to override the `is_active` method

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've made it work using the property `default=False`. It is also needed to link the `active` field to the property `is_active` of the `UserMixin` to allow Flask-Login to control the access accordingly the user is active or not:

```py
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email_confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean(), nullable=False, default=False)

    @property
    def is_active(self):
       return self.active

# Versions checked:
# Flask==2.1.2
# Flask-Login 0.6.1
```